# How to name a template file for the following theme hook suggestions?

Tags: theming, blocks

I hardly managed it to create theme hook suggestions to work with different bean blocks, so I can use custom .tpl files like:

```
bean--{bundle_name}.tpl.php // currently only bunde is 'zielgruppe'
```

Here is the code so far:

```
/**
 * Override or insert variables into the block templates.
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  // For bean blocks.
  if ($variables['block']->module == 'bean') {
    // Get the bean elements.
    $beans = $variables['elements']['bean'];
    // There is only 1 bean per block.
    $bean = $beans[reset(element_children($beans))];
    // Add bean type classes to the parent block.
    $variables['classes_array'][] = drupal_html_class('bean-' . $bean['#bundle']);
    // Add template suggestions for bean types.
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'bean__' . $bean['#bundle'] . '_tile';
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'bean__' . $bean['#bundle'] . '_' . $bean['#entity']->delta;
  }
}
```

But for the last suggestion I just cant figure how to freakin name the file. `delta` prints `"für-angehende-lehrkräfte"`. I've tried to following file names which dont get noticed:

```
bean--zielgruppe-für_angehende_lehrkräfte.tpl.php
bean--zielgruppe-für-angehende-lehrkräfte.tpl.php
```

(appearently stack messes up ü characters in code areas)

For instance, `bean--zielgruppe-tile.tpl.php` works.

Comment: You have non-ascii characters in machine names? You shouldn't. Can't you change delta to 'fur-angehende-lehrkraft' or something? It's not displayed to users after all.

Comment: well i guess thats the problem, using ->bid works fine. thanks :)

Comment: the weird thing is that drupal_html_class would not make this better... is there another wrapper/function to make such strings ascii-only?

Comment: [Transliteration](https://drupal.org/project/transliteration) module? Seems you will be able to figure out an answer from what you know and the pieces I was able to give to you, so I hope you'll post self-answer :)

Comment: go ahead and post this as an asnwer, i'll accept it :)

Comment: but I have no idea about using bid and stuff, all I could post would trigger low quality filter right away '-

Comment: Double check the database ans make sure that it can store these non-ascii characters.  Drupal likes to store all kinds of things in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you have non-ASCII characters in your machine names.  That is not a good idea, because they are used in file system constructs and your file system's character set encoding for non-ASCII characters is not necessarily the same as Drupal's internal character set encoding (UTF-8).  Since the machine names are never displayed to users, the simple workaround is to only use ASCII characters in machine names.

Just replace the non-ASCII characters in your machine names with ASCII near equivalent characters (ü → u and so on), and you will not have to guess how to create file names matching your machine names.

PS: Note that this answer is just an expansion on the upvoted comment made by Mołot on Feb 13th. I think a full answer may help future readers.  However, I'll delete it if the OP posts a self-answer or if Mołot prefer to expand the comment into a full answer himself.

Comment: youre not getting an upvote since, as you said, molot already answered it but for some reason did not post an answer, so here you go. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also output the theme_hook_suggestion with DSM. You'll see all the suggestions and template candidates for your content. (https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer could help you too)